# 5 Star Rating on Mobile with MoSync 3.3.1

Tags: android, rating-system, mosync

I was required to build a prototype 5 star rating. I searched on the Google and it works fine on website but when i try to integrate it into Mo-sync 3.3.1, it failed.

The rating will be messed when I rate it for few times. For example, if i give 5 stars, maybe 2nd and 4th star will not be highlighted but the rest of the star is highlighted. I working on it with HTML code and integrate it inside on Mo-sync.

```
    .rating:hover .rating-star:hover,
    .rating:hover .rating-star:hover ~ .rating-star,
    .rating-input:checked ~ .rating-star 
    {
     background-position: 0 0;
    }


    .rating-star,
    .rating:hover .rating-star 
    {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    display: block;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    background: url('http://kubyshkin.ru/samples/star-rating/star.png') 0 -16px;
    }
```

The code is the part that i think the problems lies on. Is it any way to 'refresh' the css after i have done the rating for once? The fiddle is the complete code for it. http://jsfiddle.net/ghvNn/531/

I was just a newbie programmer and i will appreciate any helps. Thanks in advance for all the helps.